# How to do (or workaround) \set height or width in postgreSQL in pgAdmin 4 Query Tool?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I need to

```
\set height 4
\set width  4
```

in my PostgreSQL-Code.
Since it would be too complicated to write and test my queries in psql (shell), I do it in the pgAdmin4 Query Tool.

But some code like `\set` does not work there. Do I need plugins or sth?

Btw. I use PostgreSQL Version 12.2

Comment: Well, `\set height` only makes sense in a console to begin with. But why do you need it? This looks like a strange thing that needs testing

Comment: You know psql has \edit to bring up an editor? \set is psql specific so it will not work outside it. If you show how you are using the height and width variables in your query we might be able to make other suggestions.